# What are F0 counters in Speech signals? What is represented by F0?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, speech-processing, pitch, fundamental-frequency

I can't find any dedicated definition for Frequency **F0** counters. Can anyone tell me what does **F0** exactly mean, I am confused about that.

Comment: $f_0$ is the fundamental frequency of a signal.

Comment: These are just two random symbols thrown together. I'd also say, it's most like just an unusually-noted fundamental frequency $f_0$, but that's just pure guesswork. Tarun, we'll need you to supply some reference / context.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [source](https://medium.com/@neurodatalab/pitch-tracking-or-how-to-estimate-the-fundamental-frequency-in-speech-on-the-examples-of-praat-fe0ca50f61fd)

> To begin with, let’s remember what the fundamental frequency is and in
>   what tasks it may be needed. The fundamental frequency, which is also
>   referred to as F0, is the vibration frequency of the ligaments when
>   pronouncing voiced sounds. When pronouncing unvoiced sounds, for
>   example, by whispering or uttering hissing and whistling sounds, the
>   ligaments do not vibrate, which means that this characteristic is not
>   relevant.
>   *Note that the split on voiced/unvoiced sounds is not equivalent to the split on vowels and consonants.
>
> The variability of the fundamental frequency is quite large, and it
>   can vary greatly not only between people (for lower average male
>   voices the frequency is 70–200 Hz, and for women it can reach 400 Hz),
>   but also for one person, especially in emotional speech.
>
> F0 is used in a wide range of solutions:
>
> ```
> Emotion Recognition
> Sex determination (male/female voices)
> Speaker deterioration, or splitting the speech into phrases
> In healthcare, detection of the pathological characteristics of the voice (for example, using the acoustic parameters of Jitter and
> ```
>
> Shimmer): F0 could be used for the detection of signs of Parkinson’s
>   disease [1](https://medium.com/@neurodatalab/pitch-tracking-or-how-to-estimate-the-fundamental-frequency-in-speech-on-the-examples-of-praat-fe0ca50f61fd); Jitter and Shimmer can also be used for Emotion
>   Recognition

Comment: It's not very usual to refer to a single frequency $f_0$ in bold, capital notation – that typically indicates something like vector-valuedness, randomness or being a matrix, depending on the context.